# Do all web requests contain the requestor's IP?

Tags: asp.net, ip-address, webrequest

Am I able to depend on a requestor's IP coming through on all web requests?

I have an asp.net application and I'd like to use the IP to identify unauthenticated visitors.  I don't really care if the IP is unique as long as there is something there so that I don't get an empty value.

If not I guess I would have to handle the case where the value is empty.

Or is there a better identifier than IP?

Comment: "I'd like to use the IP to identify unauthenticated visitors." - what if there are 100 machines on an intranet that use the same external ip?

Comment: What technologies are you working with here? There are a number of authentication frameworks out there.

Comment: It's ok if the IPs are not unique per user.  I'm just interested in making sure I can identify 'anonymous' users somehow but I don't care if it means 1 or 100 users.

Comment: I considered cookies, but I don't really need to make sure I'm tracking the same user over sessions, just that I'm tracking 'a' user.

Comment: What if both an authenticated user and an anonymous user are coming to your site from behind a proxy server? They would both have the same IP. Also, if the user is behind a proxy farm their IP address could change from request to request. I should think you would want some kind of session state for authenticated users, and everybody lacking that is anonymous.

Comment: ongle - yes, that is ok for me.  I don't really care if the IPs are unique per user.  I'll just use them to identify anonymous users in a more granular fashion than a huge anonymous group.  Though, you bring up a good point about users who's IP changes on each request... that might be a problem.  Maybe a question for another time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this from  `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]`.

It doesn't hurt to be defensive. If you're worried about some horrible error condition where this isn't set, check for that case and deal with it accordingly.

There could be many reasons for this value not to be useful. You may only get the address of the last hop, like a load balancer or SSL decoder on the local network. It might be an ISP proxy, or some company NAT firewall.

On that note, some proxies may provide the IP for which they're forwarding traffic in an additional HTTP header, accessible via
 `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`. You might want to check this first, then fall back to `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` or `Request.UserHostAddress`.

It's certainly not a bad idea to log these things for reference/auditing.

Comment: +1 and you can add the list of issues with REMOTE_ADDR that it gets a bit funky when IPV6 is being used.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this value is set by your web sever and there is really no way to fake it as your response to there request wouldn't be able to get back to them if they set there IP to something else.

The only thing that you should worry about is proxies. Everyone from a proxy will get the same IP.

Answer (score 2):

You'll always get an IP address, unless your web server is listening on some sort of network that is not an IP network.  But the IP address won't necessarily be unique per user.

Answer (score 1):

Well, web request is an http connection, which is a tcp connection and all tcp connections have two endpoints. So, it always exists. But that's about as much as you know about it. It's neither unique nor reliably accurate (with all the proxies and stuff).

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  every request must have an IP address, but as stated above, some ISP's use proxies, NAT or gateways which may not give you the individual's computer.

**You can easily get this IP (in c#) with:**

string IP = Context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();

**or in asp/vbscript  with**

IP = request.servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR")

Answer (score 0):

IP address is not much use for identifying users.  As mentioned already corporate proxies and other private networks can appear as a single IP address.

How are you authenticating users?  Typically you would have them log in and then store that state in their session in your app.